# Determine index of elements in a vector which occur only once

Tags: r

I have a vector e.g. like this:

```
vec <- c(6, 6, 10, 13, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 19)
```

I want now the positions of the elements which occur only once:

```
3, 12
```

Unique only ignores the values when they already have occurred.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option:

```
which(!(vec %in% vec[duplicated(vec)]))
#[1]  3 12
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
 which(vec %in%  names(table(vec))[table(vec)==1] )
# 3 12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `ave`, like this:

```
> which(as.logical(ave(vec, vec, FUN = function(x) length(x) == 1)))
[1]  3 12
```

Since `ave` doesn't seem popular, here's a twist on `duplicated`:

```
which(!(duplicated(vec) | duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE)))
```

It performs quite well... as does `ave` too, by the way :-)

```
## A bigger vector to hunt through
set.seed(1)
vec <- sample(c(1:9, sample(10:1000, 100000, TRUE)))

## Some functions to test
roland <- function() which(!(vec %in% vec[duplicated(vec)]))
am1 <- function() which(as.logical(ave(vec, vec, FUN = function(x) length(x) == 1)))
am2 <- function() which(!(duplicated(vec) | duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE)))
mb <- function() which(vec %in% names(table(vec))[table(vec)==1] )

## The benchmarks
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(roland(), am1(), am2(), mb())
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq       max neval
#  roland()   6.869534   8.781927  13.83998   9.332151  10.577182  67.52081   100
#     am1()  15.778865  16.992881  23.74078  18.394768  20.341746  74.58536   100
#     am2()   4.764585   6.340731  11.20347   7.004970   7.492049  65.00799   100
#      mb() 117.185928 122.187247 132.90390 124.526029 127.875117 233.82788   100
```

Comment: Where's the `rle` solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg It says it depends on an increasing sequence of numbers. I don't see a fast way to modify it to remove that restriction.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm assuming that was a tongue-in-cheek answer :-) .  Sadly, I fear you'd have to start off with `which(unique(rle(data)$values) & rle(data)$lengths==1)`    (not valid code)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `rle`:

```
with(rle(sort(vec)), match(values[lengths==1], vec))
[1]  3 12
```