# find unique rows depending on ID in R

Tags: r, subset

that's just a small piece of my entire data frame (year and scientific name of the fish):

```
dput(fishery)
structure(list(Year = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), Scientific.Name = structure(c(15L, 
1L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 18L, 15L, 
17L, 15L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 1L, 15L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
22L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 18L, 
2L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 7L, 18L, 2L, 18L, 17L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
1L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 
1L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 13L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 
7L, 15L, 16L, 1L), .Label = c("Aristaeomorpha foliacea", "Aristeus antennatus", 
"Centrophorus granulosus", "Citharus linguatula", "Dipturus oxyrinchus", 
"Gadus morhua", "Helicolenus dactylopterus", "Heptranchias perlo", 
"Hexanchus griseus", "Lepidopus caudatus", "Lepidorhombus boscii", 
"Leucoraja melitensis", "Lophius budegassa", "Lophius spp", "Merluccius merluccius", 
"Mullus surmuletus", "Nephrops norvegicus", "Parapenaeus longirostris", 
"Phycis blennoides", "Raja clavata", "Raja montagui", "Scyliorhinus canicula", 
"Todarodes sagittatus", "Torpedo nobiliana", "Trachurus spp", 
"Aspitrigla cuculus", "Illex coindetii", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Sepia elegans"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), .Names = c("Year", "Scientific.Name"))
```

I'd like to know the `Scientific.Name` field that compare for each `Year`.

For example, the name `Aristaeomorpha foliacea`of the `Scientific.Name` column is a common entry for both 2009 and 2010 while `Scyliorhinus canicula` has been caught only in 2009 and not in 2010.

I hope I made myself clear enough..

BTW, the entire data frame in very very huge..

Thanks

Comment: this is somehow similar and should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143857/determine-index-of-elements-in-a-vector-which-occur-only-once

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(fishery); fishery[ , .N , by = c("Year","Scientific.Name") ]`

Comment: `with(fishery, table( Year, Scientific.Name))`

Comment: You could try `library(dplyr);fishery %>% group_by(Scientific.Name) %>% filter(n_distinct(Year)==2);`

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't something as simple as `table(fishery$Scientific.Name , fishery$Year)` work?

I don't quite understand the mapping of the years to the names in the above example.

Comment: (And yes, I would have put a comment would I have sufficient points).

Comment: Hi @spitshine.. your answer is ok, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. I'm trying to "filter" the `Scientific.Name` column in order to display only the common fish species that have been always caught. So I'm not interested in a species has been caught only in 2009 and not in 2010.. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You need to be a little more specific: Do you want to look at species found in consecutive years, many years or all years? The answer will most likely be inserting a counting column (easiest with data.table, see @Simon's comment above) and selection on it.