# column of unique values between of two other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

sample data:

```
col1    col2
<NA>    cc
a       a
ab      a
z       a
```

I want to add a column `unique` with these values -- any valued that isn't shared between col1 and col2.

```
col1    col2    unique
<NA>    cc      cc
a       a   
ab      a       b
z       a       za
```

I tried using `setdiff` but

(for replication purposes:)

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = 
                   "col1    col2
    NA  cc
                 a      a
                 ab     a
                 z      a
                 ")
```

Like this:

```
df$unique <- paste0(setdiff(df$col1, df$col2), setdiff(df$col2, df$col1))
```

But it returns

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "unique", value = c("<NA>cc", "abcc" : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 3
```

From the error it looks like it's generating a vector of the differences between the columns, instead of the differences between the elements...

Edit: Added `z` and `a` sample data in last row.

Comment: So you want just the different letters between the two columns?

Comment: Yes.. Exactly that

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using `setdiff` and `Reduce` in base R:

```
cols <- c(1,2)    
df$unique <- unlist(lapply(apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) 
                  Reduce(setdiff, strsplit(na.omit(x), split = ""))), paste0, collapse=""))

  # col1 col2 unique
# 1 <NA>   cc     cc
# 2    a    a       
# 3   ab    a      b
```

Comment: where do I specify the columns here?

Comment: @RafaelMartins what do you mean?

Comment: What if `df` had 10 columns and `$unique` was to be the difference between `col1` and `col2`

Comment: @RafaelMartins updated. Just set the `cols` with the columns of interest.

Comment: Late follow up, but I just noticed that if there are no shared characters between `col1` and `col2` then it only returns the value in `col1` instead of both. I added a row to my sample data

Answer (score 1):

Here is a length method with `apply`.

```
apply(df, 1, function(i) {
              i <- i[!is.na(i)] # remove NAs
              if(length(i[!is.na(i)]) == 1) i # check length and return singletons untouched
              else { # for non-singletons
                i <- unlist(strsplit(i, split="")) # strsplit and turn into a vector
                i <- i[!(duplicated(i) | duplicated(i, fromLast=TRUE))] # drop duplicates
                paste(i, collapse="")}}) # return collapsed singleton set of characters
[1] "cc" ""   "b"
```

Note that for c("cc", "a", "c"), this will return "a" because "cc" and "c" will be marked as duplicates.

Comment: Hi. I am not sure what the second `duplicated` does, can you clarify this?

Comment: The first `duplicated` goes from front to back marking duplicates. The second one does this in reverse. This way, you can capture any elements that have a duplicate. Other wise, the first observed element (which has a duplicate below) will not be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I see. From this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/29143949/3926543, it seems that two `duplicated` approach is also very fast.

Answer (score 1):

We need to split the string first:

```
df$unique <- mapply(function(x, y){
    u <- setdiff(union(x, y), intersect(x, y))
    paste0(u[!is.na(u)], collapse = '')
}, strsplit(df$col1, ''), strsplit(df$col2, ''))

# >df
#   col1 col2 unique
# 1 <NA>   cc      c
# 2    a    a       
# 3   ab    a      b
```